# Google Analytics code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I need to edit the existing GA code on our WordPress website with a different code and i intend to do the same by using add header/footer script plugin but i don't know if that will replace the present code. I tried to find the same on the server to change via FTP (as with our magento site) but was unsuccessful, can anybody update me on the same please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit this via the admin itself. If you use as plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Otherwise, to edit GA, is not in the files itself, but within the admin. I would look within your admin, there is a lot of resource out there with wordpress integrations. You should almost never need to look in the code to find this. (that's the purpose of wordpress). I couldn't exactly say where yours is, but take a look at all your wordpress plugins/integrations and configurations.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything within the admin as such to replace the existing code, will the plugin recommended by you give the option to change the existing code specifically as i don't see the same in the screenshots...

Comment: @shamz are you positive you have a GA tag showing on your website? If you find it in the view source. you could grab the ID or an identifier and use a tool to search in all files, I use Sublime Text. It allows me to search every file in a directory for text. Just another option that could help you locate the hardcoded GA tag (if it exist).